# How to pass an array of objects to Java with swig?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, swig

I am working on a Java app that has a callback from a native c library. The callback passes back the following c struct;

```
struct session
{
    unsigned media_count;/**< Number of media.      */
    media *media[10];   /**< Media array.   */

};

struct media
{
    struct
    {
        char    media_name[];   
    } desc;

/*
  Stuff im not interested in..  
*/
};
```

In the swig interface file I have the following;

```
core.i
------

typedef struct session
{
    unsigned    media_count;
} session;
```

Then in the Java callback implementation I end up with;

```
void call_back(session session) {
    session.get_media_count();
}
```

As expected, however I now want to expose the media array to Java. I have the following;

```
core.i
------

struct media
{
} media;

typedef struct session
{
    unsigned    media_count;
    media media[10];
} session;
```

But this is giving me a single media item in Java eg;

```
void call_back(session session) {
    session.get_media_count();
    media media = session.get_Media();
}
```

When I want;

```
void call_back(session session) {
    session.get_media_count();
    media[] media = session.get_Media();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A while ago I solved a similar task by creation of a custom read-only "vector-like" class with `at()` method exposed as `get(int i)` on java level. The main idea is that you don't have to have the same class on native and swig level. Actually you construct SWIG-level almost independently from C/C++ level. The key method of the construction is `%extend` SWIG-directive, something like this:

```
%{
#include "session.h"
%}
%extend session {
    const media& getMedia(int i) {
        return media[i];
    }
}
```

But be aware, that while performing tricks like that I literally felt that I was doing something really evil. Like studying The Dark Forces from "Harry Potter" ;-) And afterall, I discovered that doing a lot of Java<->native code switches performs not that good as expected.

Also I doubt you could return an "array object" from native code and use it safely from Java, because such an access heavily depends on low-level data alignment, and you don't have methods to directly translate C-level data to Java-level data without extra copyings

Comment: This is by far the simplest (and therefore probably best solution), however I'd add a `%ignore` directive to avoid the generation of a confusing `getMedia()` call too.

Comment: Well, as I understand, he/she doesn't have `media* getMedia()` right now. But yes, if it exists in C-level, it can be deleted in Java level

Comment: Thanks for the advice, in the end i just made a native helper function to process the media :)